# How to convert a .blend file to .md3 or .iqm format?

Tags: file-format, linux

I have a thing I made in blender that I want to add to cube2 sauerbraten; that is a game similar to quake.  My problem is, I can't export the file into either of those two formats, so I can't get it to work.  What do I need to do?  I am running ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may want to utilize files that either came from other 2D or 3D software, or you may want to use the things you have made in Blender and edit them in other software. Luckily, Blender offers a wide range of file formats (e.g. OBJ, FBX, 3DS, PLY, STL, etc.) that can be used to import and export.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export.html

Then import / convert the file your program requires.

Also you can try online tools
Online 3D Model Converter - File Formats
https://www.greentoken.de/onlineconv/

`Blender Export from 2.81 to MD3 Model Format`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjvSA7dpWXQ

And another one but will depend on the version of blender and python you are using.
https://github.com/mino-git/rtcw-wet-blender-model-tools

Comment: I already looked at all those sites; notice NONE of them can export a file in one of the needed formats.  Blender can't do it either.  I can do it as a .obj, or k3d, but not .md3 or .iqm.

Comment: Looks like it depends on the version of Blender the .blend file may have been created with.
This guy actually made a video with the title  
`Blender Export from 2.81 to MD3 Model Format`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjvSA7dpWXQ

Add what version of Blender your using to your question.

Comment: Also it may depend on the version of python your using.
This Developer created a script that does this.  You may want to email him/her and ask about the best version of blender to use.
https://github.com/neumond/blender-md3

Comment: And another one but will depend on the version of blender and python you are using.
https://github.com/mino-git/rtcw-wet-blender-model-tools

Answer (score 0):

Blender MD3 exporter:
https://github.com/neumond/blender-md3

There's one for 2.79 that definitely works that I'm using right now. I think a guy name Der_Ton made it IIRC.

Also, check out Katsbits:
https://www.katsbits.com/tools/